# How can I retrieve my Bluetooth device UUID over BLE?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, android-bluetooth

This is likely a very basic question. Our device has a new Bluetooth module.

After retrieving my device from a list of bonded devices I can no longer find a UUID. I can, however, find the device and retrieve its MAC Address, which I know is commonly used to connect over BLE.

Old module:

https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/BM78#additional-features

New module:

https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/bm70#additional-features

Is this simply because my new module doesn't support communication over SPP?

My app is written using the Android Bluetooth classic library.

Does this mean I need to rewrite the Bluetooth communication portion of my app for BLE?

Comment: When in doubt check the data sheet for each product, but I believe your understanding is correct. Data sheets for hardware will list out hardware specifications/protocols as well as capabilities/limitations. See the documents tab in the links you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you'll need to rewrite your app to handle BLE, just [follow this guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le). 
You can use [BLE-Scanner app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.macdom.ble.blescanner) to debug BLE and to see what data is being used.